# My overlay is affecting the whole card instead of just the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm setting up several Bootstrap media objects and I want for a FontAwesome icon to show up on the image as an overlay when the mouse hovers, once clicked this opens a fancybox.

I've tried moving things around quite a bit, but at this putting I think I'm having tunnel vision. Please help!

My code snippet:

```css
/**The CSS I've been trying to use: **/

  .overlay-hover:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.85;
    transition: 1s ease;
  }
  .overlay-hover:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .overlay {
    transition: 1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3 shadow">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="media">
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300"style="height:125px;width: auto" class="mr-3" alt="...">
           <div class="media-body">
           <h5 class="mt-0">Title</h5>
           <p>Text</p>
           <span class="badge badge-primary">One</span>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Not being able to achieve the results I want, so hopefully someone will be able to easily tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check the below snippet, have answered your question.
It might be possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555112/9380480

Comment: The overlay classes aren't even applied to the HTML in your example please read on how to post a [mcve]

Comment: Your html doesn't even use the class `overlay` or `overlay-hover`, of course it won't work...

Comment: Hence I said I've moved things around and couldn't figure it out, so I prefered to provide a clean code hoping that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you were looking for?

```css
   
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }
}

.container .title {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .content-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-details {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadeIn-bottom {
  top: 90%;
}

.media-body {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 0!important;
}
.card-body {
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 card bg-light  shadow ">
      <h4 class="text-center">Card 1</h4>
      <div class=" card-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">

              <div class="content">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
                  <div class="content-overlay"></div>
                  <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
                  <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h5 class="mt-0">Title</h5>
                <p>Text</p>
                <span class="badge badge-primary">One</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 card bg-light  shadow ">
      <h4 class="text-center">Card 2</h4>
      <div class=" card-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-9">

                <div class="content">
                  <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
                    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
                    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
                    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h5 class="mt-0">Title</h5>
                  <p>Text</p>
                  <span class="badge badge-primary">One</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've tried applying your code to what I'm trying to achieve, but couldn't get it to work as it's expanding the width of the image taking the space from the text. Could you please have a go at implementing it on my example on your end please? Thanks!

Comment: please update the code which you have tried at your end in jsfiddle. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/43q76a8s/). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I want it to look like the original code snippet, but with the addition of an overlay on the image.

Comment: I'm afraid you are running into the same issues I was, which is the image now completely overtook the space of the card. I've updated the snippet with an additional card showing how I want it to look as a whole.

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you need. In the above solution border, red color is a card, both the title and image are inside the card. Please edit and update the question for better understanding.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't provide an updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9per1jvn/). The bottom example is the desired result, but with the addition of the overlay only over the image and not the whole card.

Comment: Please check the solution now. Updated the snippet

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much Sai! :)

Comment: Glad to know that I'm able to help you. Happy coding